# JBOSS 7.0 WebProfile configure Oracle 11g Driver

Tags: oracle, jboss, datasource

I've configured JBOSS datasource with a new module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle.jdbc">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

in the folder %JBOSS_HOME%\modules\com\oracle\jdbc\main

I put in the "main" folder also the driver itself: ojdbc6.jar

Then i configure a datasource with driver:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/MyPool" pool-name="MyPool" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@my.server.com:1521:mydbname</connection-url>
        <driver>oracle</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>myusername</user-name>
            <password>mypassword</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.jdbc"><xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class></driver>
    </drivers>
```

When I start the application server i receive the error:

**New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
   service jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle (missing)**

The configuration seems to be good to the documentation, may be there is problem with the version of JBOSS or Oracle Driver?

Thanks

Comment: I try a lot of variations for the <driver> part:
<driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.jdbc" />
or changing che Driver name, with xa or without.